# Add a password validation in a form_for before submitting review (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, passwords, form-for

I m new on Ror.

I would like to add a password_field in my form_for before creating a review for a specific product. This review.password should match with a product.reviewcode:

- if it matches the review is created for this product.
- if not you have a notification: "Wrong password...Try again.."

I'm working on it for days, but impossible to do this feature on my app... :-( Any Ideas... Please :-)

Here is my code:

---

```
views/reviews.form.html.erb:
<% if @reviews.present? %>
Il y a deja un commentaire.
<% else %>
<%= form_for([@product, @product.reviews.new]) do |f| %>
<div id="user_stars"></div>
<%= f.text_area :comment, rows: 3, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %><br>

<%=f.label "Mot de passe communiqué par le vendeur:" %>
<%=f.password_field :password %>


<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Evaluez", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
reviews_controller.rb:
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def create
  @review.password = nil
  unless @review.password == @product.reviewcode
   @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)
   @review.save
   redirect_to @review.product
 else
  render :create, notice: "Le code n'est pas bon"
  end
end

private

def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :star, :product_id, :user_id, :password)
end

def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id, :reviewcode])
end

end
```

---

```
product.rb:
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :reviews

  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :state, presence: true
  validates :color, presence: true
  validates :brand, presence: true
  validates :size, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 70 }
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 1 }
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
  validates :reviewcode, presence: true

  def reviewcode
    reviewcode = "1234"
  end
end
```

---

```
review.rb:
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user

validates :comment, presence: true
validates :star, presence: true
validates :product_id, presence: true
validates :password, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. Do you know where you're having issues? I notice you have `@review.password = nil` in your controller. It looks like the review password will always be nil. Is that intended?

Comment: when you define `@product` in your `create` action?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using unless.
Unless is basically saying "if not ", so in your code 
`unless @review.password == @product.reviewcode` means `if @review.password != @product.reviewcode`. Additionally as [Derek Hopper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9104680/derek-hopper) commented, you are setting the password alway to `nil`, I don't know if that's intended.

`reviews_controller.rb`

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    # @review.password = nil I think this should be deleted
    if check_password
      @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)
      @review.save
      redirect_to @review.product
    else
      render :create, notice: "Le code n'est pas bon"
    end
  end

private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :star, :product_id, :user_id, :password)
  end

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id, :reviewcode])
  end

  def check_password
    return @review.password == @product.reviewcode
  end

end
```

**EDIT**

As for you comment, I'm guessing you have another method in your `reviews_controller.rb` in which you "call" the view. In this method you should have something like this:

```
def new
  @review = @product.reviews.new
  #Use this @review insted of @product.reviews.new in the html file
end
```

Comment: Thks for your fast replies, But I still have the following issue:   NoMethodError in ReviewsController#create
undefined method `password' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #27):
def check_password
    return @review.password == @product.reviewcode
  end

end

Comment: Thks Chester, but still not working :-(  And not so far to succeed...... Well...Without the condition: "if check_password" in my Review Controller /create action: The review is correctly created for the product. But if I add this condition it returns me: NoMethodError in ReviewsController#create       undefined method `password' for nil:NilClass... (I don't use new method in my Review Controller: I display directly the form in my product show by calling <%= render:'reviews/form' %>)

Comment: So if instead of calling check_password you run that bit of code directly on the create action it works?

Comment: It is not working...even with integrating the condition directly in the create metod instead  of def check_password

Comment: You have a new instance of review after that bit of code. As i sad before in your show method for product you should do somehting like `@review = @product.reviews.new` and pass it as a parameter to the form

Answer (score 0):

Thk to: @ChesterLaborde , @Derek Hopper , @ inye
So here is the final issue. No need to create a method in the Product model. And new action is directly included in the Product Show then in the Review Controller just need to proceed this way (if I need for exemple a code equal to my product.price*10):

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)
    if check_password
      @review.save
      redirect_to @review.product
    else
      redirect_to @review.product, notice: "Le code est incorrect"
    end
  end

  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :star, :product_id, :user_id, :password)
  end

  def check_password
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    return @review.password == @product.price*10
  end

end
```